# Looping over a dataframe and referencing a series

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate over a data frame in python and in my if statement I reference a couple of columns that happen to be a Series.  When i run my code I get the following error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**Data**:
Taken from solution provided by @CypherX.

```py
template = ['some', 'abra', 'cadabra', 'juju', 'detail page', 'lulu', 'boo', 'honolulu', 'detail page']
prev = ['home', 'abra', 'cacobra', 'juju', 'detail page', 'lulu', 'booboo', 'picabo', 'detail here']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Template': template, 'Prev': prev})
```

```
      Template         Prev
0         some         home
1         abra         abra
2      cadabra      cacobra
3         juju         juju
4  detail page  detail page
5         lulu         lulu
6          boo       booboo
7     honolulu       picabo
8  detail page  detail here
```

---

My code is the following:

```
for row in s:
    if (s['Template']=='detail page') and (s['Template']==s['Prev']):
        s['Swipe']=1
    else:
        s['Swipe']=0
```

where `s` is my dataframe.

What can I do to fix this? Any ideas?

Comment: That's not how iterating a df works. Try `for row in s: print(row)` to see what I mean. For better help, please see [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your post to provide a [mcve] with sample input and output

Comment: Okay but I think you understand what I'm trying to do...

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using `0` and `1` instead of a boolean?

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the value of `s['Swipe']` using `np.where` instead:

```py
import numpy as np

s['Swipe'] = np.where((s['Template'] == 'detail page') & (s['Template'] == s['Prev']), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be something like this:

```
s['Swipe'] = (s['Template'] == 'detail page') & (s['Template'] == s['Prev'])
```

You might convert result from boolean to int then, if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you did not provide any reproducible problem data, I made my own and here is the solution.

## Short Solution

```py
condition = ((df.Template==df.Prev) & (df.Template=='detail page'))
df['Swipe'] = condition.astype(int)
```

## Solution in Detail

Evaluate the condition to a `boolean` and since you want to assign 1 for `True` and 0 for `False`, just a conversion from `boolean` to `int` would do the job.

```py
# Prepare Dummy Data
template = ['some', 'abra', 'cadabra', 'juju', 'detail page', 'lulu', 'boo', 'honolulu', 'detail page']
prev = ['home', 'abra', 'cacobra', 'juju', 'detail page', 'lulu', 'booboo', 'picabo', 'detail here']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Template': template, 'Prev': prev})

# Evaluate Condition
condition = ((df.Template==df.Prev) & (df.Template=='detail page'))
df['Swipe'] = condition.astype(int)

print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
      Template         Prev  Swipe
0         some         home      0
1         abra         abra      0
2      cadabra      cacobra      0
3         juju         juju      0
4  detail page  detail page      1
5         lulu         lulu      0
6          boo       booboo      0
7     honolulu       picabo      0
8  detail page  detail here      0
```

## What was the problem in your solution?

1. Your code iterates over the dataframe `s` (note: normally `s` is used for series and `df` for dataframe), and returns the column names. So the `row` actually will not return the rows of the dataframe.
2. Even if you had the row information, you are not using the `row` anywhere in the code, inside the for loop.

```py
for row in s:
    if (s['Template']=='detail page') and (s['Template']==s['Prev']):
        s['Swipe']=1
    else:
        s['Swipe']=0
```

I will print out the output with the dataframe `df` to make my point:

```py
for row in df:
    print(row)
```

**Output**:

```
Template
Prev
Swipe
```

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @RyanBall: I added some justification to why your code did not work in the first place. Also, please see how I created a simple reproducible dataframe so anyone could verify the solution quickly. Please make sure to add such reproducible data to your stackoverflow questions whenever possible. Also, please consider **`voting up`** my solution if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

2 quick ways I can think of:

1. Without using numpy

```
    s['Swipe'].loc[(s['Template']=='detail page') & (s['Template']==s['Prev'])]=1
    s['Swipe'].loc[(s['Template']!='detail page') | (s['Template']!=s['Prev'])]=0
```

2. Using numpy (like how one of the above answers have already specified):

```
    import numpy as np    
    s['Swipe'] = np.where((s['Template'] == 'detail page') & (s['Template'] == s['Prev']), 1, 0)
```